# Android Studio GridLayout

Tags: android, imageview, android-gridlayout

I am new with android studio and trying to work with Gridlayout. I added a grid layout to the blank activity but everytime I drag a view to gridlayout and drop it nothing happens and my grid layout is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Gridlayout is not supported in the designer of the latest Android Studio versions (yet).

You should another Layout (ConstraintLayout, LinearLayout) or use XML directly. The preview should work just fine.

Comment: I've used GridLayout fine... At least the support GridLayout

Comment: You probably used it by typing directly your XML in the editor and not using the designer. Am I right?

Comment: It's been awhile. I do remember that the editor could at least manage the column stretch and cell-ordering. I don't remember dragging from the Palette onto it

Comment: You're right, it is not just not supported in the latest versions but will come back soon

Answer (score 0):

With GridLayout in Android Studio 2.3 you can drag the first component over layout in Component Tree. After this, you can drag others components to GridLayout.